# SQL Query - How to apply different conditions (Where clause?) to specific aggregated columns

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I have a table (simplified example below) consisting of TEST(s), TESTPRICE per test and TESTSTATUS.  I would like to be able to run a query that will result in two aggregated columns, one for pending revenue and one for started revenue per test group.

[image: tblREQUEST]

I can easily generate two seperate result tables by executing the following:

```
SELECT
    Test
    ,SUM(TESTPRICE) AS 'PendingRev'
FROM
    REQUEST
WHERE
    TESTSTATUS = 'P'
GROUP BY
    TEST
ORDER BY
    TEST
SELECT
    Test
    ,SUM(TESTPRICE) AS 'StartedRev'
FROM
    REQUEST
WHERE
    TESTSTATUS = 'S'
GROUP BY
    TEST
ORDER BY
    TEST
```

This results in two out put results like this:

[image]

[image]

However, I would prefer a single output result table like this:

[image: Desired Output]

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, advise on a technique I can read up on - I've tried a few different approaches (subqueries, etc.) but the closest I seem to get is a total sum for a given TESTSTATUS in all rows, or errors

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation, which in most databases looks like this:

```
SELECT Test, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TESTSTATUS = 'P' THEN TESTPRICE END) AS PendingRev,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TESTSTATUS = 'S' THEN TESTPRICE END) AS StartedRev
FROM REQUEST
GROUP BY TEST
ORDER BY TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot to achieve the same result:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af5025/11)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
PIVOT (SUM(TESTPRICE)
 FOR TESTSTATUS IN ('P' as PendingRev  , 'S' as StartedRev ));
```

Comment: Thanks Atif, really appreciated